# Cucumber java Chromedriver not being found

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber

I am running a Cucumber Java project in Intellij on Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed the latest version of Chromedriver and Chrome. Does anybody know how to fix this error?

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'driver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:
```

Comment: Why are you using Spring Beans to create the Chrome Driver. Have you tried using the recommended steps in Cucumber tutorials?

Comment: This is just the repository that I downloaded. If you can, may you please send me a link to a cucumber tutorial that demonstrates how to set it up? Thank You

Comment: https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: When learning a new technology, it is always best to go directly to the source to learn the basics.

Comment: Eric, did the tutorial work for you or do you still need help resolving this issue?

Comment: It was actually because of my ~/.bashrc fiile. In my Pom.xml file: the environment variable for chromedriver was named something different from what I had defined in my ~/.bashrc file.I was able to get it up and running. Thank You for your help.